# alternative to in_array (php)

Tags: php, html, arrays, forms

Doing a quiz page where 3 random questions will display and the user must enter the correct answer. After clicking the submit button, the answers entered(form input) as well as the correct answers will be stored into separate arrays and passed over to the result page. From there, I will compare between these two arrays. As of now, I'm using `in_array` however, i found out it's not the correct method because the answer can be entered at every question and still be awarded correct. Is there a correct method to compare the 2 arrays?

Quiz.php

```
<?php
$qtspool =
      array(  1=> array('qts'=>'What is my name?', 'ans'=>'Lu'),
              2=> array('qts'=>'What is the module code?', 'ans'=>'307'),
              3=> array('qts'=>'What is missing char abde?', 'ans'=>'c'),
              4=> array('qts'=>'What is missing number 1345?', 'ans'=>'2')
      );
      
      $qtspick_key = array_rand($qtspool,2);
      for ($i=0; $i<2; $i++)
      {
          $qtspick_key[$i];
      }
      
      $pickqts = array();
      $i = 0;
      foreach ($qtspick_key as $key)
      {
          $pickqts[$i] = $qtspool[$key]; 
          $i++;
      }
      
      ?>
      

      <form method="post" action="results.php" >
        <br>
        <?php 
        foreach($pickqts as $qtsno=>$value)
        {
            ?>
            <?php echo $value['qts']; ?>
            <input name="user_ans[]" type="text" >
            <input type="hidden" name="answers[]" value="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($value['ans']); ?>" />
            <br>
            <?php       
        }
        
        ?>
        
        <input type="submit"/>
        </form>
```

results.php

```
 <?php
    
    $correctanswer = 0;
    $incorrectanswer = 0;
    
            $ansArray = array();
            $ansArray = $_POST['answers'];
    
            foreach($_POST['user_ans'] as $textans)
            {
    
                if (in_array($textans, $ansArray)) {
                        
                    $correctanswer++;
                    
                }
                else {
                    $incorrectanswer++;
                }
            }
            echo $correctanswer;
            ?>
            <br>
            <?php
            echo $incorrectanswer;
            ?>
```

Comment: First of all, it doesn’t make that much sense, to send the correct answers together with the form in the first place. You should rather put your data array into an extra file, so that you can _include_ it in both quiz.php and result.php.

Comment: Why would you put correct answers into the HTML, practically allowing users to use a cheat sheet? You should rather place a question id alongside the answer, so you can easily lookup what the correct answer is based on the question.

Comment: Also, array indexes usually start at 0, not 1. Get used to following that pattern, there are usually no benefits in deviating from that, but a couple of potential drawbacks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply check for the value at the same index.

```
foreach($_POST['user_ans'] as $i => $textans)
    $correctanswer += $ansArray[$i] == $textans ? +1 : -1;
```